# How do I create the Calculated column that references three different static, hidden field value columns in 3 separate content types?

Tags: calculated-column

Danny:
You wrote:

> Create a new SiteColumn in each of the 3 ContentTypes with a static
>   (unique) Text value for each (eg. the ContentType name)
>
> Hide these SiteColumns in the 3 ContentTypes
>
> Create a new Calculated SiteColumn where you can reference the above 3
>   SiteColumns and output the value you want.
>
> Assign this Calculated Column to all 3 ContentTypes

I can create 3 different site columns, add them to their respective content types and hide them - no problem.

How do I write the Calculated column formula that references the 3 different site columns and picks a value?  I am having trouble doing this.

Comment: As a Column on the List (where those 3 ContentTypes are used)